# Pause screen update while rendering pdf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am making an app in ios that renders a pdf at certain zoom levels. The method looks good but while it is rendering i'd like just to keep the screen paused instead of seeing the rasterized tiles. Is there a way to pause the screen on beginning the process and then show the finished product when done. Something like...

`[mainScreen pauseScreen];  //method I'm trying to find`

`[self redrawPDF]; //this method works fine`

`[mainScreen resume]; //show finished product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if it is possible to pause rendering a context to the screen, but you can render to an off-screen bitmap, and then quickly render that bitmap to the screen. This will hide the process of rendering from the end users.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/410313/335858) to the Stack Overflow answer explaining the process of rendering to an offscreen bitmap.

Comment: I'm upvoting because this may be the only solution, it still changed the image for the worse before it got better, however. I tried even taking a screenshot, displaying it, and then dismissing when rendering was done. Looked bad, way worse than the pixilation. I just found better points to re-render in the end. Leaving open with some outside hope there is a way